# How do find $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ in the case below?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$f:  \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} $ defined by $f(x + n\mathbb{Z})=mx+n \mathbb{Z}$.

$\operatorname{Im}(f)$ actually ought to be $d\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, where $d=\gcd(m,n)$.

$\operatorname{Im}(f)=\{y+n\mathbb{Z} \, | y \text{ is divisible by m}\}.$ I don't know how to incorporate $d$ in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)=(m\mathbf Z+n\mathbf Z)/n\mathbf Z=d\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Can you also explain a little, please?

Comment: Oh I get it now. $d=mp+nq$.

Comment: That's right. One of the definition of $\gcd(m,n)$ is it's the positive generator of the *principal*  ideal $m\mathbf Z+n\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Hi. Can you also explain how to get $ker(f) \cong \mathbb{Z/dZ}$?

Comment: Did you see the three *isomorphisms  theorems*? It is the 3rd.